# Multiple CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS data payloads

Tags: php, json, curl

Here is what I have done so far. I make a curl request and pass a json to the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS fields. This works alright. The problem is I want the code to run for multiple users which are in a json

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.url.com',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "customerName":"Eugene Afet",
    "mno":"MTN",
    "amount":1,
    "msisdn":"233546888444",
    "description":"Payment For Tickets at My shop",
    "reference":"kRybiV4lllVwddlly3N2BW1"
},
{
     "customerName": "james",
     "mno": "MTN",
     "amount": 1,
     "msisdn": "2330987654",
     "description": "Awaiting",
     "reference": "0asa0wwww00aaabfbsubfhbj" 
    }',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

What works, when the json is only one. I have read about curl_multi_exec but I am not sure how to apply it here.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.url.com',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "customerName":"Eugene Afet",
    "mno":"MTN",
    "amount":1,
    "msisdn":"233546888444",
    "description":"Payment For Tickets at My shop",
    "reference":"kRybiV4lllVwddlly3N2BW1"
}',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: I think you would just loop and set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` each time with different JSON.

Comment: I tried that too, it didn't work @AbraCadaver.